# Failed to display multi-page tiff by tiff.js using Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tiff, tampermonkey

Hello I am new to stackoverflow.

I am planning to display a 2-4 page A4 size tiff over a document processing webpage by using Tampermonkey in Chrome.

I dig around the Internet and found that [Seikichi's tiff.js](https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js/tree/master) can be used to display multi page tiff with [the example from him](http://seikichi.github.io/tiff.js/multipage.html).

However, when I insert the code above and link the tiff.min.js to tampermonkey, only the tiff from the example webpage could be displayed.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         ShowTiff
// @namespace    ShowTiff
// @version      0.1
// @description  ShowTiff
// @author       ShowTiff
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// @require      http://seikichi.github.io/tiff.js/tiff.min.js
// @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js     
// ==/UserScript==

$(function () {
        Tiff.initialize({TOTAL_MEMORY: 16777216 * 10});
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', "http://seikichi.github.io/tiff.js/images/multipage.tiff");
  xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  xhr.onload = function (e) {
    var buffer = xhr.response;
    var tiff = new Tiff({buffer: buffer});
    for (var i = 0, len = tiff.countDirectory(); i < len; ++i) {
      tiff.setDirectory(i);
      var canvas = tiff.toCanvas();
      $('body').append(canvas);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
})();
```

Which means, when I tried to replace the tiff image from other sources, such as the multipage tiff sample from [this website](https://www.nightprogrammer.org/development/multipage-tiff-example-download-test-image-file/), it failed to display. Only the original test image with fruits from the link above could be displayed successfully in my webpage.

I was wondering would that be the problem of color space, resolution and file size of various tiff images. But all of those "other source" images could be shown successfully when I saved Seikichi's sample page to local, open with Dreamweaver and replace the source to other tiff images. So I don't know if there's any problem on tampermonkey and the tiff javascript library, as well as the code.

Happy if anyone could help resolve this, thank you very much!

Edit: As requested to amend in GM_xmlhttpRequest

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         ShowTiff
// @namespace    ShowTiff
// @version      0.1
// @description  ShowTiff
// @author       ShowTiff
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @require      http://seikichi.github.io/tiff.js/tiff.min.js
// @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$(function () {
        Tiff.initialize({TOTAL_MEMORY: 16777216 * 10});
  var xhr = new GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://seikichi.github.io/tiff.js/images/multipage.tiff",
  responseType: "arraybuffer"
 });
  xhr.onload = function (e) {
    var buffer = xhr.response;
    var tiff = new Tiff({buffer: buffer});
    for (var i = 0, len = tiff.countDirectory(); i < len; ++i) {
      tiff.setDirectory(i);
      var canvas = tiff.toCanvas();
      $('body').append(canvas);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
})();
```

Comment: Userscript should use GM_xmlhttpRequest, look for examples.

Comment: If that's switched to GM_xmlhttpRequest, even the original test image failed to display as well.

Comment: Show your code with GM_xmlhttpRequest, it might be incorrect. Note, you'll have to use `@grant GM_xmlhttpRequest` instead of `@grant none`.

Comment: Do you mean the code inside the request function? I think it's inside the tiff.min.js.
And new image also failed to show with '@grant GM_xmlhttpRequest' along with 'GM_xmlhttpRequest'

Comment: GM_xmlhttpRequest is a different API so it should be used differently, you can't just replace XMLHttpRequest with GM_xmlhttpRequest. This is why I suggested looking for examples. Show us the code that you came up with.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't show my HTML page currently as it involves many personnel particulars, it takes time for me to eliminate and post it here, sorry about that.
However, as what I saw by applying to other website using wildcard *://*/* , it get the same result as well.
Taking the blank black page http://about.black as an example,
The original "http://seikichi.github.io/tiff.js/images/multipage.tiff" works well and display successfully,
but when replaced with "http://www.nightprogrammer.org/wp-uploads/2013/02/multipage_tiff_example.tif", it doesn't show either.

Comment: No need to show HTML. I'm asking you to show the modified userscript that uses GM_xmlhttpRequest.

Comment: I am not familiar with the format of GM_xmlhttpRequest, could it be written as above? Thanks.

Comment: No. This is why I suggested looking for examples. We're going in circles so I'm out.